# Why does this system of linear equations give me a linearly independent vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the vectors $\mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, \mathbf{v}_2 = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ - 1 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$ we want to find a third vector $\mathbf{v}_3$ such that these three vectors form a base in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Usually you would approach this problem by the definition of linear independence $\sum a_i \mathbf{v}_i = \vec{0}$.

However I found through an incident that you can also write following system of linear equations

$$\begin{align}b_1 \mathbf{v}_1^1 + b_2 \mathbf{v}_1^2 + b_3 \mathbf{v}_1^3  &= b_1 0 + b_2 1 + b_3 2 &= 0 \\
b_1 \mathbf{v}_2^1 + b_2 \mathbf{v}_2^2 + b_3 \mathbf{v}_2^3 &= b_1 2 + b_2 (-1) + b_3 4 &= 0
\end{align}$$

where the $\mathbf{v}_i^j$ denotes vector $\mathbf{v}_i$'s $j$-th entry.

We can rewrite this system and solve it using the gauss-jordan-algorithm.

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -1 & 4 & 0\end{array} \rightarrow \begin{array}{ccc|c}0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 6 & 0\end{array} \rightarrow \begin{array}{ccc|c}0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 3 & 0\end{array}$$

This leads us that for $\mathbf{v}_3 = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}$, the entries are $x_1 = -3, x_2 = -2, x_3 = 1$ which indeed gives us a linear independent vector.

**How can it be that this system of equations gives us an linearly independent vector even it is different from the definition?**

**Is there a name for "building" a linearly independent base with this approach where do I find a proof for it?**

Comment: what is the linearly independent vector you're talking about? $<2,0,6>$ is not independent of the other two basis vectors

Comment: You are solving for a vector $b$ that is orthogonal to $v_1,v_2$, which is a reasonable approach.

Comment: Just as an aside, almost any 'random' vector you select will form a basis. A computation procedure that works in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is to use the cross product, that is choose $v_3 = v_1 \times v_2$.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake while editing.

Comment: @copper.hat ah yes you are right. Does this approach always lead to a solution?

Comment: Well, any non zero $b$ that satisfies the above equations will work.

Comment: Orthogonal vectors are linearly independent bjt

Comment: There's something called the Gram-Schmidt process, where you take vectors and "build" an orthogonal base out of them. Then use the fact that orthogonal vectors are always linearly independent.  Look it up if you're curious.